# SharePoint 2013 Performance Point

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-2013

Dashboard designer error:

> The url is not available,does not reference a sharepoint site, or you
>   do not have permission to connect

This is happening to the site collections under one web application only in the whole Farm. Other web applications are working fine and I can open site collections through dashboard designer.

Any suggestions????

Unattended acc is all set, Site feature is activated, site collection is added to trusted location. On database side, app pool acc has db owner access to web app db. PPS is db owner there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this indicates to a deployment issue on this app. Maybe something went wrong when deploying webparts, the assemblies couldnt be registered or were not copied correctly. It could also be a specific access restriction issue in SharePoint or in the file system that SharePoint relies on.
Without any log information it is hard to say what is really the problem - but - have a look at windows event log for any further indications, the general log files that sharepoint/asp.net write or also consider using monitoring tools that can tell you more details on what is happening here.
I recently wrote a blog on top deployment mistakes in SharePoint. I highlight exactly these deployment mistakes in more details: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160818030846/http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2015/03/03/5-sharepoint-deployment-performance-health-checks-beyond-making-sure-its-running/)

Andi